# In newer Windows, window is tiny with no borders

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista

I've been working on updating an old (Windows 95-era C API) application. While it works fine on Windows XP, on Vista and newer it always displays in a tiny 240x160 window with no menus or borders. What are the differences between Vista and XP that could cause this behavior?

On Windows 7, it looks like this (actual size):

[image]

This is what it should look like, and what it does look like in Windows XP:

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot. Is that a 16-Bit application?

Comment: This question is way too broad; you have to help us help you.

Comment: What it looks like in Windows 7 (actual size): http://imgur.com/s1sIX

What it should look like (and does in XP): http://imgur.com/VZlWn

Hope that helps, though I don't see what information this adds.

Comment: This looks like a DPI problem. What happens if you run the app in XP compatibility mode? You say that you're working on the code—can you post some of it? If you can get a minimal example going by ripping out unnecessary code from a copy of your original project, that could give us something to work on.

Comment: XP compatibility mode doesn't do a thing in this regard. I'm only kinda working on the code -- I'm linking new code against a disassembly of the original -- so it's quite difficult to minimize. If DPI stands for "Dots per inch," then I have no idea how that's relevant.

Comment: I found a workaround a while back. After switching into full-screen mode (based on DirectDraw) and back, the borders appear as normal. I've programmed it to do this on startup. This greatly increases startup time, so it's not ideal.